# Generate PHP code coverage without Xdebug

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm using Xdebug to get some coverage data during my unit tests, but it costs a lot of time (and memory).

Is there any way to get coverage without using Xdebug?

Comment: _but it costs a lot of time_ hopeflully you have a DEV-stage (or server) and not running test on PROD-stage (or server) ;-)   Also you can group tests, to not always run all tests at once.

Answer (score 13):

As of PHP 7, you can use PHPDBG instead of Xdebug to collect code coverage information with PHPUnit. However, there will always be a resource penalty (time and memory) when code coverage information is collected.